# 2 android radiogroups into one horizontally

Tags: c#, android, mono

I have 2 radio groups that I would like to be combined into one. I want them to be horizontal, not vertical. Is there any way to wrap it or merge them? I can't figure it out. I am just starting to learn programming. The language I am using is C#  Here is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <RadioGroup
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1">
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />
        </RadioGroup>
        <RadioGroup
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup2">
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton5" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton6" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: combining them on the runtime or not?

Comment: Hi. how do you want to combine the two radiogroups into one? do you mean you want only one radiogroup with six radiobuttons instead?

Comment: how can u want just put it in a diagramatic manner... otherwise people didn't understand ur problem....